# web pack - awesome-typescript-loader plugin : how to detect [at-loader] process ending

Tags: bash, webpack

In the webpack build script, the 'awesome-typescript-loader' is started as a separate process. When webpack exit, this separate process is not yet finished , and so I cannot run the PM2 reload process...

Is there a way to detect the end of this separate process to start the PM2 reload correctly on time ?

To check the webpack timeline , I added a specific plugin

```
new WebpackShellPlugin({onBuildStart:['echo "Webpack Start"'],
 onBuildEnd:['echo "Webpack End"'], onBuildExit:['echo "Webpack Exit"']})
```

running :

```
 node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail
```

console log :

```
@example.com Executing pre-build scripts
@example.com "**Webpack Start**". # echo from  WebpackShellPlugin
@example.com 
@example.com [at-loader] Using typescript@2.0.10 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from /opt/hello-angular/releases/20161206103220/tsconfig.json
@example.com 
@example.com [at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...

    # is there a way to keep track this process ?

@example.com 
@example.com [at-loader] Ok, 5.531 sec.
@example.com Executing post-build scripts
@example.com "**Webpack End**"  # echo from WebpackShellPlugin
@example.com Executing additional scripts before exit
@example.com "**Webpack Exit**". # echo from WebpackShellPlugin
@example.com Hash: 5c4be87232dc5ea6d7fa
@example.com Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.27
@example.com Time: 70161ms
@example.com     Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
@example.com bundle.js  376 kB       0  [emitted]  app
@example.com     + 441 hidden modules
...
....  # [at-loader] output  long process ....
5693ms asset optimization
....
@358ms emitting
localhost$.  #  [at-loader] process finished )
    is there a way to get warned when the separate process ends up, and run my pm2 start command at this point ?
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, using a callback function in my shipit task ...

```
// this task builds the Angular bundle in the release folder
shipit.blTask('build_script', function () {
    shipit.remote('cd '+ shipit.releasePath + ' && npm run build:' + env).then(function (res) {
        console.log("WEBPACK BUILD CALLBACK FUNCTION... NOW RESTART PM2");
        shipit.start('pm2-startOrReload');
    });
});
```